# Is there a point where it would make more financial sense to charter a flight than to buy tickets?

Tags: air-travel, budget, airlines, charter

Say you're going from point A to point B and the only [reasonable] way to get there is by airplane (eg an island to mainland). Pretend your group is LARGE (at least 12 people)

Is there a breaking point where you should give a try at looking for a charter flight as opposed to booking such a large group in a commercial airline?, or, (I don't know if this is common practice) would commercial airlines have like a wholesale fare for this type of situations, thus making it more accessible than chartering a flight?

Comment: Charter flights costs depends on maaany things, but take a look at [this website](http://www.avchart.com/users/quotes/default.asp) for an estimation.

Comment: @machlas thanks, that seems like a useful site, if you know how to find out about airlines having a group discount (and if possible of how much tipically if applicable) you could just post and answer  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is, and yes, airlines do have a group discount. This depends on a lot of factors however. I know dive resorts who charter one whole airplane every 5 days since they change the complete occupancy of their quite remote resort each time.

You will never know until you ask though since the availability of open seats in regular airplanes is a main driving factor for the price.

Answer (score 13):

I once ended chartering a flight because we (2 travellers) missed a booked flight. Buying a new single ticket would cost us 2200 Euro each. In the neighbouring country (400 km) there was a flight for 660 Euro. Chartering a cessna 172 to fly to the neighbouring airport was possible for 750. 
So here chartering a flight saved us 4400-2070=2130 Euro. 
Although being quite frustrated for missing the initial flight, having the opportunity going to airport security with your "own" pilot in contrast to a boarding pass was quite the experience.

So my point is that even with very small group it might be worthwhile to charter a flight.

Most travel search engines end at a group of 8 persons. So with 12 people I would always try to contact the airlines that is offering that trip. Enquiring is always free.